# JQuery modification to table search

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I currently have JQuery code to search a table on the first column and sort by row. However, it is including additional note information that we want excluded from the search so the search is only limited to system name information.

```
SearchFilter.customfilter = function(searchInput, table) {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById(searchInput);
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById(table);
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

This is a sample row of HTML table that is being searched:

```
      <tr>
        <td><a href="site.html">System Name</a>
          <p class="tablenote"><small>Note: System note information. </small></p>
        </td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>
```

Is there a good way to modify the jquery code to exclude the tablenote information from the search like excluding that tablenote class or excluding small text?

Comment: so.... look at the contents of only the anchor tag. You can't just say "Get all innertext except that which is inside of a specific child element". To get that result you'd have to instead iterate over all child nodes and then filter out the one you don't want, and search within the remaining. for each cell. for each row.

Comment: How do I look at the contents of only the anchor tag? Can you suggest some specific code?

Comment: no. that's just dom traversal.

Comment: Okay. Can you or someone point me to some material that would guide me in incorporating that concept of isolating the anchor tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) (together with the [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector) to filter out results that are inside any elements with the class `.tablenote`. The key code would be something like:

```
var inputText = "Joel";

var $matches = $('.row').find(':contains(' + inputText + ')').filter(function(){
    // only include matches that are *not* inside an .info element
    return $(this).closest('.tablenote').length == 0;
});

var rowContainsInput = ($matches.length > 0);
```

So that's essentially saying "tell me if this row contains the input text, but **not** if it's inside a `.tablenote` element.

See my [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v281gwsu/).

**NOTE:** However, if you have control over the markup in the first place, it would be better to add a class to the System Name anchor (like `<a href="..." class="system-name">System Name</a>`) and then specifically target `$row.find('.system-name')`. Or even better yet it would be better to mark the system name anchor with a data attribute like: `<a href="..." data-system-name>System Name</a>` and then you can target it like: `$row.find('[data-system-name]')`.